# What are good examples of "Dynamic opaque predicates"?

Tags: software, obfuscation

I am studying the concept of software obfuscation and come across this interesting scheme, dynamic opaque predicate:

[image]

Basically it either goes two false branches, or two true branches, and therefore, three statements will always be executed.

I am looking for some implementations of this scheme, for instance, what would be a good example of preparing condition `p` and `q`? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your illustration is a perfect example of the scheme. It would not be too hard to write a simple program yourself that executes like `if(x){l1();}else{l1();l2();}if(!x){l2();l3();}else{l3();}`. Since this is probably not what you want, I wonder if you are asking for a tool that obfuscates code in such a manner.

Comment: @MechMK1  Actually, this is exactly what I am looking for.. Thank you!